# whether the following sets are disjoint or not..?

Tags: real-analysis

If A is a closed set,then what can we say about closure of A^C ? It is a closed set.But my doubt is whether A and closure of A^C is disjoint or not?

what i had tried is:
if A is closed, A = closure of A.
A and A^C is disjoint, so closure of A AND A^C is disjoint.Can anyone help me to understand whether they are disjoint or not..

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use a favorite example.

Consider the closed set $A = [0, 1] \in \mathbb R$.

What is $A^c$?: $\;A^c = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, +\infty)$.

Now what is the closure of $A^c$ in $\mathbb R\;?:\;$ That would be $(-\infty, 0] \cup [1, +\infty)$.

Now, consider $A \cap \overline{A^c} = [0, 1]\cap\left((-\infty, 0] \cup [1, +\infty)\right)$. Are $A$ and $\overline{A^c}$ disjoint?

Comment: no..they were not disjoint

Comment: You're right. So does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes..thank you..i have to constuct two disjoint closed sets in a metric space..if A is closed,then what will be disjoint close set of A,Can u give me some hint to think this

Comment: Consider $[0, 1] \in \mathbb R$ and $[2, 3] \in \mathbb R$. These are disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: but arbitrarily how u choose a disjoint closed subset

Comment: if the only thing u know is A is a closed subset of some metric space X,how u will choose the other disjoint closed subset

Comment: Any two sets which fail to share any elements are disjoint. The same is true of closed sets: so long as they share no elements, they are disjoint. For two (closed or otherwise) subsets $A, B$ of $X$, if $A\cap B = \varnothing$, $A, B$ are said to be disjoint.

Comment: I can understand..but my question is how u choose the closed set using the property that A is closed

Comment: You can choose *any closed subset* of $X$ that shares **no** element with $A$. So if $A = [x, y]$, then $B$ can be any closed subset in the metric space such that its elements $b \in B$ are such that $b \lt x$ or $b > y$

Comment: sir if u dont know anything about A,HOW WILL U CHOOSE. if u choose A^C, it will be disjoint,but will it be closed? that is why i was thinking about closure of A^C..but it is not working